# Issue with Expo Snack, d3-shape library, error: Unable to resolve module '@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault.js'

Tags: reactjs, react-native, d3.js, expo

I am trying to move my project from local development into expo snack, I shift everything over and I get the following error:[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dP6mx.png)

When I comment out d3-shape it loads! But I cant figure out how to resolve this? [Imports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0Qhk.png)

Here are my dependencies

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "react-native-paper": "^5.10.4",
    "@react-navigation/native": "6.0.0",
    "@ant-design/icons-react-native": "^2.3.2",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.17.11",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "*",
    "d3-shape": "^3.2.0",
    "expo-font": "~11.1.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.3",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.9.0",
    "react-native-svg": "13.4.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.0.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.5.0",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.20.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons/AntDesign": "*"
  }
}
```

Help!

I have tried resolving the error using expo snack, and searching for relevant stackoverflow questions but none of them seemed to tie to d3-shape issue

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)